# How do I send a response schema in a MERN Stack?

Tags: express, mongoose, redux, mern

I am building a website using mongoose for the database and I currently trying to write an express route that doesn't send back the data stored at a given ID but a response schema with a description of each property, a definition of the data type for each property, and whether the property is optional.

For example, this is the model that I use for each product that is stored in my database

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
     name: {type: String, required: true},
     description: { type: String, required: false },
     image: {type: String, required: false},
     expirationDate: { type: Date, required: true },
     postedUser: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true }
    }, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

This is the route that I have written to retrieve the data at a given product ID.

```
router.route('/').get((req, res, next) => {
   Product.find(req.query)
     .then(products => {
        res.json(normalizer(products));
     })
     .catch(err => next(err));
 });
```

Similarly to how the url localhost:5550/product/?_id=5ef5521062186e0190da17c9 returns the data stored at the given ID, I would like to create a route that returns the model used for products when calling the url localhost:5550/product/schema/?_id=5ef5521062186e0190da17c9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.schema` property on a model to get access to its schema

```
router.route('/').get((req, res, next) => {
   console.log(Product.schema)

   res.json(Product.schema)
 });
```

I'm not sure if it is `.schema` or `.Schema` you'll have to test it out